# Running Lambda Function written in Go on AWS - error while loading shared libraries

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-sam

My question is similar to: [libtensorflow.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096379/libtensorflow-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) but I do not see an answer for it, so I would appreciate any kind of help.

Once I print my **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** I get the following output:

```
/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib
```

I have created and deployed TensorFlow Lambda Layer.

To my knowledge Lambda Layers should be cached in /opt/bin directory, right? But on documentation:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-layers.html I see that default cache directory is `~/.aws-sam/layers-pkg`.

Once I try to run my Lambda function with AWS SAM, and once I uncomment code which uses package in which I import tensorflow with go library, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtensorflow.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have even tried to include these libraries in **lib** directory, and I've made that lib directory as part of **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**. Same result.

Comment: Did you find any solution?